# Is it possible to execute a VIM command in a non-interactive mode on an already open VIM?

Tags: vim, gvim

Let's say I have an open VIM with file loaded already and I want from an outside script/GUI to execute a VIM command on this opened VIM.
For example, I have several locations in the file that I want to jump to from a TK GUI by pressing a button, so each time a press the button I would like to jump to another location.

Comment: see also vim.stackexchange.com

Comment: If the Vim instance was started with a server, yes. If not, it's horribly ugly to try and control. See http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7966/what-are-practical-uses-of-the-client-server-mode and http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5354/how-do-i-close-vim-externally/